# Swift: how to call NSSpeechRecognizer func

Tags: macos, swift, speech-recognition

My speechRecognizer func doesn't seem to be called. I couldn't find anything in the documentation about calling this func.
Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSSpeechRecognizerDelegate {

let SR:NSSpeechRecognizer = NSSpeechRecognizer()
var commands = ["word","hello"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SR.commands = commands
}

override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}

@IBAction func Listen(sender: AnyObject) {
    SR.startListening(); print("listening")
}

@IBAction func Stop(sender: AnyObject) {
    SR.stopListening()
}

func speechRecognizer(sender: NSSpeechRecognizer,
    didRecognizeCommand command: AnyObject?){

        if (command as String == "word")
        {
            println("case word")
        }
        else if (command as String == "happy")
        {
            println("case happy")
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `NSSpeechRecognizerDelegate` to `self`:

```
SR.delegate = self
```